# Thhead уменьшается при прокрутке

Tags: html, javascript

http://www.tetrapolis.ru/yslygi_phis_licam/deposit/ вот создал я табличку, но при прокрутки вниз плавающий элемент (thhead) не соразмерно уменьшается - почему и как это исправить

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var HeaderTop = $('thead').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > HeaderTop ) {
                    $('thead').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px' , width:'100%'});
            } else {
                    $('thead').css({position: 'static', width:'100%'});
            }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thead у вас не уменьшается, это можно увидеть, открыв консоль: http://clip2net.com/s/ia8jr2 .

А вот ячейки начинают занимать ровно столько места, сколько контента в них вставлено. Почему это произошло? Когда заголовок таблицы был `position: static`, он находился в общем потоке и ячейки в нем растягивались на ширину таблицы. Когда вы делаете заголовок `position: fixed`, он выпадает из стандартного потока и у ячеек нету родителя, под чью ширину им растягиваться. И простым путем вам не получится выравнять ячейки в заголовке под ширину столбцов таблицы, т.к. их ширина зависит от ширины контента, т.е. всегда будет меняться.

Выходом может быть установка фиксированной ширины для ячеек (заголовка и тела, если вы обратите внимание, то ячейки тела таблицы тоже изменили размер после отсоединения заголовка)

Comment: подскажите пож-та с установкой фиксированной ширины - я в js  не силён

Comment: Вам в этом случае js не нужен, CSS вполне справится с этой задачей :)
Вам нужно выставить ячейкам заголовка и таблицы одинаковую ширину:

    <theaad>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 100px;">...</th>
            <th style="width: 50px;">...</th>
            <th style="width: 50px;">...</th>
            и т.д.
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100px;">...</td>
            <td style="width: 50px;">...</td>
            <td style="width: 50px;">...</td>
            и т.д.
        </tr>
    </tbody>

Comment: спасибо, утром додумал ваш совет, сделал почти так же 
<tr class='even'><th><div style="width:85px;text-align: center;">Вклад</div></th>

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать css3 свойство transform: translate(x,y); Это точно поможет, решите только вопрос с кроссбраузреностью и счетчиком высоты.

Comment: не, css3 не вариант, мне нужно что бы эта штука работала в 8 осле, а можно осуществить подмену на картинку верхней части таблицы при прокрутке?